# How to make Arduino serial communication with Mathematica

Tags: microcontroller-kit

Arduino sketch code for the pms3003 dust sensor.

```c
#include (SoftwareSerial.h)       //RX, TX library

SoftwareSerial Serial1(2,3);         //RX ,TX pin 2, 3

long pmcf10=0; 

long pmcf25=0;

long pmcf100=0;

long pmat10=0;

long pmat25=0;

long pmat100=0;

char buf[50];

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);          //start serial 
  Serial1.begin(9600);        //RX, TX 

}


void loop() {

  int count = 0;

  unsigned char c;

  unsigned char high;

  

  while (Serial1.available()) {               

    c = Serial1.read();           //RX, TX save c

    if((count==0 && c!=0x42) || (count==1 && c!=0x4d)){

      Serial.println("check failed");

      break;

    }

    if(count > 15){

      Serial.println("complete");

      break;

    }

    else if(count == 4 || count == 6 || count == 8 || count == 10 || count == 12 || count == 14) {

      high = c;

    }

    else if(count == 5){             //pm1.0

      pmcf10 = 256*high + c;

      Serial.print("CF=1, PM1.0=");

      Serial.print(pmcf10);

      Serial.println(" ug/m3");

    }

    else if(count == 7){           //pm2.5

      pmcf25 = 256*high + c;

      Serial.print("CF=1, PM2.5=");

      Serial.print(pmcf25);

      Serial.println(" ug/m3");

    }

    else if(count == 9){           //pm 10

      pmcf100 = 256*high + c;

      Serial.print("CF=1, PM10=");

      Serial.print(pmcf100);

      Serial.println(" ug/m3");

    }

    else if(count == 11){

      pmat10 = 256*high + c;

      Serial.print("atmosphere, PM1.0=");

      Serial.print(pmat10);

      Serial.println(" ug/m3");

    }

    else if(count == 13){

      pmat25 = 256*high + c;

      Serial.print("atmosphere, PM2.5=");

      Serial.print(pmat25);

      Serial.println(" ug/m3");

    }

    else if(count == 15){

      pmat100 = 256*high + c;

      Serial.print("atmosphere, PM10=");

      Serial.print(pmat100);

      Serial.println(" ug/m3");

    }

    count++;

  }

  while(Serial1.available()) Serial1.read();

  Serial.println();

  delay(5000);

}
```

Can I run this with Mathematica commands? I would like to know how to connect the pms3003 dust sensor to Arduino and how to do serial communication using Mathematica.

Comment: What you are asking is feasible.  May I suggest that you start with a much simpler Arduino sketch, like a simple blink function.  You may find [this example](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/936358) helpful.  If you have trouble with that example, we should be able to help you get it running.  We would need to know what kind of OS (Linux, Windows, Raspbian) you are using, which version of MMA, which Arduino (Uno, etc), etc.  There is also information under "Arduino" in MMA's documentation

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
For an Arduino-connected device, can you see an example of obtaining serial communication values using Mathematica?

Comment: I do not want to convert the entire Arduino sketch code to Mathematica. I want to get the serial communication value of the device using Mathematica.

Comment: I don't really see what this has too do with Arduino or the code you posted - if I understand your question correctly, you simply need [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/device/Serial.html)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments by Lucas Lang, you just need the the [Serial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/device/Serial.html) connection framework to do this.

```
dev = DeviceOpen["Serial", "put the port name here"]
```

Acquire the data

```
fromSensor = {};
task = SessionSubmit@
   ScheduledTask[AppendTo[fromSensor, FromCharacterCode@DeviceReadBuffer[dev]], 5];
```

It's up to you how you want to parse it. But to see everything that's coming in

```
Dynamic[fromSensor]
```

And when you are done

```
TaskRemove[task];
DeviceClose[dev]
```